# Azure Function with Event Hub trigger writes 1 event to storage and not working in batch

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-eventhub

I have a azure function trigger with event hub trigger that gets events from the event hub. I wrote this code to handle the events and save it to storage account.
the problem is that the events are not saved in batch but 1 at the time. How can I save a batch of 500 events in one file and not 500 separate files.

```
import logging
import numpy as np
import azure.functions as func
def main(event: func.EventHubEvent, outputblob: func.Out[bytes]):
    for ev in event:
    outputblob.set(ev.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

I try working with the binding setting, but it did not work.

```
  "extensions": {
    "eventHubs": {
        "maxEventBatchSize" : 10,
        "batchCheckpointFrequency" : 1,
        "prefetchCount" : 300,
        "transportType" : "amqpTcp"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code to handle the events and save it to storage account.

Comment: The code is now in the question

Answer (score 0):

1. Created EventHub in portal and EventHub trigger function in vs code.
2. created storage account and container to save the file containing the stored events.
3. Sending three random event messages to event hub and saving in a file and storing in a container in storage account.

   Tried below code:
   ***Init*.py**

```py
from  asyncio  import  events
import  logging
import numpy as  np
import azure.functions as  func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

storage_connection_string='XXXXXXXXXX'
container_name = 'sample-workitems'
def  main(event: func.EventHubEvent):
for  ev  in  event:
logging.info(f'Function triggered to process a message: {ev.get_body().decode()}')
logging.info(f' SequenceNumber = {ev.sequence_number}')
logging.info(f' Offset = {ev.offset}')

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string,container_name, "filename")
blob_client.upload_blob(ev.get_body().decode(),blob_type="AppendBlob")
```

Using the reference of  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send)  on Send/receive events to & from event hubs using python:

**send. py**

```py
import  asyncio

from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventData
Pravueventhub_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB= "Eventhub connection string"
async  def  run():
producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=Pravueventhub_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB, eventhub_name="eventhub")

async  with  producer:
event_data_batch = await  producer.create_batch()
event_data_batch.add(EventData('First event '))
event_data_batch.add(EventData('Second event'))
event_data_batch.add(EventData('Third event'))
await  producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

**function.json**

```json
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
{
"type": "eventHubTrigger",
"name": "event",
"direction": "in",
"eventHubName": "eventhub",
"connection": "Pravueventhub_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB",
"cardinality": "many",
"consumerGroup": "$Default",
"dataType": "binary"
}
]
}
```

**Result:**

[image]